# Securely rate limit an API, prevent IP address spoofing

Tags: php, api, security, ip-address, cloudflare

I'm developing an API using PHP, MySQL, and Redis and would like to rate limit particular calls. The API is sitting behind CloudFlare. To implement this, I'll be incrementing the count per hour each IP address makes for a particular call in Redis, and will present an error if it exceeds the limit.

However, I believe I've run into an issue with IP address spoofing. I know the real client will never receive a response back if they spoof their IP address, but that may not be necessary for a call such as a create account call. A client could effectively create a DoS attack by registering for many accounts, all with different IPs, all the while avoiding the rate limit. This would cause my system to send out a high volume of welcome emails (leading to my servers being marked as spam), and could prevent users from signing up if their email account was maliciously registered. How can this be avoided?

My thoughts:

- Does SSL prevent this form of IP spoofing?
- Is there a way to make sure the client receives the server's response, thereby ensuring that it's not a spoofed IP address?
- Does cloudflare somehow verify the IP address is not spoofed when passing along the `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` header?

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: if your application is using TCP then you dont have to worry about it

Comment: "IP spoofing" is something completely different than what you're talkinga bout. A user hopping between IPs is **NOT** spoofing. that's just how the net CAN work, depending on the user's provider(s). e.g. consider a user on a cellphone who's on WiFi while in a building, then migrating to cell data when they go outside. Two different networks, two different IPs, but not "spoofing".

Comment: and what about many users behind the same proxy?

Comment: @Marc I'm worried more about intentional and malicious spoofing, thousands of times, not someone's IP address changing once or twice during their use of the application.

Comment: @myte Good point, we will need to consider that for our application as well.

Comment: then you keep track of how many times a user has hit the API, and disallow their request when they exceed the limit. e.g. "user X has hit the api 203 times in the past hour, disable until 3am". That basically means you ignore the IP entirely. you track it completely by the username. so it won't matter WHERE that account is hitting your api from, you'll be disabling/limiting the account, not the IPs.

Comment: nowadays Ingress/Egress filtering usually prevents the attacker from spoofing the packet headers related to the originating IP-address, basically using Raw Sockets for the purpose of masquerading an internet-routable IP-address becomes useless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you would use a secret token (API key, login credentials or whatever) that identifies a user and count requests per user account.

Since you are attempting to limit the requests by IP I assume that you are about to create an "open" API where anybody may send requests too, without authentication.

The term *IP spoofing is not a problem in this case. This is because - unless he controls the routing between your server and the internet - the spoofing attacker will not get an answer (as you said). But HTTP(S) is transported over TCP and establishing a TCP connection requires the attacker to perform a successful handshake which requires to receive the connection ID from the server - meaning it requires to receive answers.

The Wikipedia Page of the TCP protocol might me a good external resource to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

You see *IP spoofing* isn't a problem. But you need to understand that rate limiting by IP isn't a good solution at all. That's because:

- an abuser could request a new IP after the limit has been reached
- your API might be used by a large organization where internal IPs get
  NATed by the core router and you see only that core routers IP.

I would strongly encourage you to use authentication (together with SSL!)
 and limit requests on a per user base.

---

Answers to the listed questions in short (Can explain more if you want)

> Does SSL prevent this form of IP spoofing?

No

> Is there a way to make sure the client receives the server's response, thereby ensuring that it's not a spoofed IP address?

Yes, it is implemented in TCP -> see `ACK` in the wikipedia link above

> Does cloudflare somehow verify the IP address is not spoofed when passing along the HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP header?

As explained above. HTTP traffic requires an established TCP connection. Therefore this makes no sense.

Comment: So what you're saying is it's not possible to trick a server using a connection over TCP into thinking that it is receiving a request from an IP that is not real?

Comment: (We are talking about HTTP requests) Unless the attacker controls either the *spoofed* IP (or network) itself: NO. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Okay, I believe I just had a misunderstanding of how TCP connections worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does SSL prevent this form of IP spoofing?

It prevents Man in the middle (MitM) attacks only as the spoofer cannot easily decrypt the messages.

> Is there a way to make sure the client receives the server's response,
>   thereby ensuring that it's not a spoofed IP address?

Defense Mechanisms
Firstly, ensure that your firewall and routers are configured correctly and restrict the advance of forged traffic from the internet. - [See more at:](http://www.firemon.com/blog/spnews/prevent-ip-address-spoofing/#sthash.8JLayUhA.dpuf)

> Does cloudflare somehow verify the IP address is not spoofed when
>   passing along the HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP header?

You can't really verify the IP address unless you have special equipment as mentioned in the above article that employs ACLs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ssl can HELP with mitm attacks, but it  can't prevent them. e.g. consider a state-level attacker who can finagle a signed SSL cert out of a registrar. it's happened before, and the only way to prevent is to have reliable 3rd party verfication of the SSL certs you're being presented with what the provider you THINK you'r connecting to actually uses. SSL is essentially toilet paper for verification. Makes you feel all shiny and tingly, but still have a coating of poop on everything.